# Ruby call to system command (Apache Bench) not waiting for completion

Tags: ruby, sinatra, exec

I'm trying to run Apache Bench via Ruby with the backticks method. Normal Apache Bench output looks like this:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1528965 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking stackoverflow.com (be patient).....done


Server Software:
Server Hostname:        stackoverflow.com
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        0 bytes

Concurrency Level:      2
Time taken for tests:   0.752 seconds
Complete requests:      10
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      4600 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    13.30 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       150.421 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       75.210 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          5.97 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       72   73   0.4     73      73
Processing:    74   77   2.2     77      81
Waiting:       74   77   2.2     77      81
Total:        147  150   2.2    151     153
```

The Ruby command I'm trying is:

```
results = `ab -n 10 -c 2 http://stackoverflow.com/`
```

It seems to work find in IRB and I get all the results back. But, when I try and hook it into my Sinatra app, I only get this back:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1528965 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking stackoverflow.com (be patient).....
```

It's as if the command isn't waiting for the ab tests to finish. What's going on here?

Comment: It does work for me (`ruby  -e "require 'sinatra' and get('/me'){ \\`ab -n 10 -c 2 http://stackoverflow.com/\\` }"`). What does your sinatra code/template look like?

Comment: Yeah, I think either the URL was malformed or not encoded properly. I'm just not getting any error back.